# REST URI Templates for Query and Command operations

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

We have an application that is split into two parts:

1. Admin - Where data is changed
2. Public - Where data is read

I'm looking at creating a REST API to provide this functionality. It's very easy to see how CRUD operations can be represented but I am not sure about specific operations (commands) on an individual resource. For example to "Publish" a `Project` we send a "PublishCommand". We don't PUT the full `Project` back to the server with its `Published` property set to `true`.

On a similar note, I am a little confused at how we should represent more advanced query operations on resources without being classed as a RPC type service.

Below I've listed the URI templates for my `Project` resource. Am I on the right track for creating a truly RESTful API?

```
ADMIN API
---------

// Project Resources
GET /projects -- get all projects
POST /projects -- create a new project

// Project Resource
GET /projects/10 -- get project with id 10
PUT /projects/10 -- update project with id 10
DELETE /projects/10 -- delete project with id 10

// Project Resource Operations
POST: /projects/10/publish -- publish project with id 10
POST: /projects/10/unpublish -- unpublish project with id 10
POST: /projects/10/setposition/2 -- move to position 2 in projects list

// Project Sub resources (identity is local to project)
POST: /projects/10/media -- adds media to project with id 10
PUT: /projects/10/media/5 -- updates media id 5 for project id 10
DELETE: /projects/10/media/5 -- deletes media id 5 from project id 10

PUBLIC API
----------

GET: /projects -- gets all projects (with default limit e.g. first 10)
GET: /projects?skip=10&take=10 -- gets projects 11 to 20
GET: /projects/tagged/rest OR /taggedprojects/rest -- gets projects tagged with "REST"
GET: /projects?orderbydesc=publishdate OR /latestprojects -- gets latest projects

GET: /projects/10 -- gets project with id 10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that REST is intended to only represent CRUD operations. Your interface looks fine to me, and I believe you're on the right track.

There's a talk online about DDD and REST: [RESTful SOA or Domain-Driven Design - A Compromise?](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/RESTful-SOA-DDD) by Vaughn Vernon.

**Update** to include a comment I made below:

You can query yor read model using GET. To mutate your domain you can PUT or POST to resources that represent commands. This would provide the richness of a domain model beyond CRUD and still use the inherent semantics of HTTP.

Comment: Will watch this. But remember, using HTTP verbs for conveying action is part of REST http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

Comment: Thanks Dennis. This is precisely my concern - I shouldn't have to compromise the the richness of my domain model just so I can provide a RESTful API to talk to it.

Comment: You can request yor queries using GET, and PUT or POST to resources that represent commands. This would provide the richness of a domain model beyond CRUD and still use the inherent semantics of HTTP. But I know that some people don't share this opinion.

Comment: @Aliostad I think he is conveying the actions correctly as he is creating projects using POST. Publish / Unpublish are operations / commands being  started / executed by the "service" so POST is correct here also and I think its more explicit then doing a PUT for a project where the published property is set to true/false for example.

Comment: My issue is with introducing new concepts into the domain just to satisfy REST. In @Aliostad's example I would "Publish" by POSTing to /publishedprojects. This satisfies REST but does not make sense in our domain.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler yeah. The point is the interactions with a resource become another resource as such its own controller. For example `/api/Project/1/Move` could be a `MoveController` with route `api/Project/{id}/{controller}`

Comment: @BenFoster this is not at the domain level. This is at the controller level. You business layers still exposes Move, Publish, ...

Comment: @Aliostad surely whether we have a `Move` method on the Projects controller or a `Post` method on a Move controller is just an implementation detail (we're still doing a POST and the URI template would be the same)?

Comment: @BenFoster Constraining your REST interface to domain concepts is far too limiting.  You need the ability to create new resources that do not map directly to the domain to overcome the limitations of only having a limited set of HTTP methods.

Comment: I have a question about command-like URI's. All of you are perfectly OK with URI like `/projects/10/publish` but this is not resource, right? And how can I recognize difference between `/projects/10/publish` and `/projects/10/media` both seems legit, both works on POST. But one is resource, other is command. Even RMM works with resource in links, not command-like URI's. Command-like URI's are not RESTful, beacuse it doesn't represent resource, but action. Right?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at publishing as a resource, then you can use CRUD (POST/GET/PUT/DELETE):

- POST to create a publish, passing project id
- DELETE to unpublish
- GET to retrieve

This does not mean that the process has to be associated with physical creation of records in database. It is just the **resource-based approach** which is important.

Comment: so we POST to /publishedprojects? What about those operations that don't really map at all to resources, such as the "Move" command.

Comment: Still you need to think of it as a resource if you are fully abiding with REST. http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

Comment: I don't see how this is possible for every operation that occurs within a domain as some operations do not map to a resource (like the "Move" example).